# How to align a hero-image with on using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to have two hero-images on the same page (index page) and I was wondering how can I align them. Since I want them to be at the same height, I want them to be in the centre with around 50px separation from each other under the header.

will the flex property work hero-images ?

```css
.hero-image1 {
    /* Use "linear-gradient" to add a darken background effect to the image (photographer.jpg). This will make the text easier to read */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://galacticsabers.co/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/mattgallodesigns_the_planet_naboo_from_star_wars_hyper_realism__92ca62a7-f8f0-458f-a6a7-49c3120150de-1024x574.png");
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: left;
  }

  .hero-image2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    justify-content: right right;
    align-items: right right;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/00/84/89/0084892bd1326bdcb2cc597820af2fdf.png")
  }

  .hero-image1, .hero-image2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  /* Place text in the middle of the image */
  .hero-text1, .hero-text2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero-image1">
  <div class="hero-text1">
    <h1>Our Bestsellers</h1>
    <a href="bestsellers.html"><button>Bestsellers</button></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hero-image2">
    <div class="hero-text2">
        <h1>Our New Arrivals</h1>
        <a href="newarrivals.html"><button>New Arrivals</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the "justify-content" property and the "align-items" property which Google told me would work but it didn't.

I also tried to align them in the most stupid way possible by using padding and margin but all that did was to mess with the rest of the page

Answer (score 1):

Embed your items inside a flex container.

A simplified example might be:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px 5px;
}

.flex-parent div {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="hero-image1">
      <div class="hero-text1">
        <h1>Our Bestsellers</h1>
        <a href="bestsellers.html"><button>Bestsellers</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-image2">
       <div class="hero-text2">
         <h1>Our New Arrivals</h1>
         <a href="newarrivals.html"><button>New Arrivals</button></a>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Mozilla has some good documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hero-image1 {
    /* Use "linear-gradient" to add a darken background effect to the image (photographer.jpg). This will make the text easier to read */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://galacticsabers.co/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/mattgallodesigns_the_planet_naboo_from_star_wars_hyper_realism__92ca62a7-f8f0-458f-a6a7-49c3120150de-1024x574.png");
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: left;
  }

  .hero-image2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    justify-content: right right;
    align-items: right right;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/00/84/89/0084892bd1326bdcb2cc597820af2fdf.png")
  }

  .hero-image1, .hero-image2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  /* Place text in the middle of the image */
  .hero-text1, .hero-text2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;">
  <div class="hero-image1">
    <div class="hero-text1">
      <h1>Our Bestsellers</h1>
      <a href="#"><button>Bestsellers</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-image2">
      <div class="hero-text2">
          <h1>Our New Arrivals</h1>
          <a href="#"><button>New Arrivals</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All you need to do is include a parent div so it can include both of your hero-image divs, and then you can align them as you would like